# Coq: "dependent induction" inside Ltac

Tags: coq, ltac

Dependent induction seems to work differently for me in an `Ltac` and not.

The following works just fine:

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.

Goal forall (x:unit) (y:unit), x = y.
intros.
dependent induction x.
dependent induction y.
trivial.
Qed.
```

`dependent induction` is overkill here, since `destruct` works just fine. Furthermore, it's not necessary to name the thing to be `destruct`ed in the proof script if `Ltac` is used to help:

```
Ltac ok :=
  match goal with
    | [H : unit |- _] => destruct H
  end.

Goal forall (x:unit) (y:unit), x = y.
intros.
ok.
ok.
trivial.
Qed.
```

However, the same `Ltac` fails when `destruct` is replaced by `dependent induction`:

```
Ltac wat :=
  match goal with
    | [H : unit |- _] => dependent induction H
  end.

Goal forall (x:unit) (y:unit), x = y.
intros.
wat.

(*
Error: No matching clauses for match goal
       (use "Set Ltac Debug" for more info).
*)
```

`Set Ltac Debug` gives no additional useful information, other than that `dependent induction` is, in fact, attempted on both `x` and `y`.

Strangely enough, if I wrap up the `dependent induction` in another `Ltac` without a match, and apply it to a term that is equal to the one I actually want to perform induction on, everything goes smoothly:

```
Ltac go H := let z := fresh in remember H as z; dependent induction z; subst H.

Ltac why :=
  match goal with
    | [H : unit |- _] => go H
  end.

Goal forall (x:unit) (y:unit), x = y.
intros.
why.
why.
trivial.
Qed.
```

What is going on here, and why is `dependent induction` seemingly so context dependent?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Have you tried testing this on the trunk version of Coq? https://github.com/coq/coq

Comment: With trunk, `wat.` fails in a more verbose way: "In nested Ltac calls to "wat", last call failed.
Error: Ltac variable H is bound to x which cannot be coerced to
a fresh identifier." `why` and `ok` both work just fine. I'm still confused.

Comment: Yup, almost sure it's a bug. It might be a good idea to file a report: https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/.

Comment: Done: https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=3784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was  indeed a bug, and it was fixed in March 2015.